Ensure a singleton variable across entire web app
Background Info
My web app is built on top of async FastAPI. The server deploying this app will start 4 workers and each worker will start 2 threads for handling concurrent requests.
Description
Most services in my web app rely heavily on a token required from an external API. The problem is that this token has a certain expiration duration, meaning I'll have to fetch it again when the existing one expires.
To prevent the token from being refreshed multiple times, I did the following things:

Cache the token in the MySQL database so that I can access the token within the expiration duration without fetching the API.
When the existing token expires, I apply an asyncio.Lock on all coroutines so that it's ensured only one coroutine can exclusively do the fetching operation.

Problems
The above approach did solve the problem but buried a hidden issue. Since I stored the token in MySQL database, I'll have to keep the connections open during the entire refresh operation (This is a bad approach as stated in SQLAlchemy docs). After referencing Python docs, I came to realize it's not an appropriate solution to apply asyncio.Lock in a web app with multiple threads.
As a result, I'm considering caching the token in redis. But then, how should I properly lock the refreshing operation so that only one token exists in redis even under high concurrency environment?

You are correct that asyncio.Lock won't help when multiple processes are involved. I'm not sure I agree that leaving a MySQL connection open is necessarily that bad, it's not like the token refresh takes that long time. But on the other hand, for storing a login token, I think Redis is the better choice regardless (faster and schema-less).

You could implement a lock with a separate field/column in your database (regardless of which one), where the process that needs to refresh the token set's the status to FETCHING or similar, and if another process notices the token has expired and the status is FETCHING, it'll just wait for it to update.

Another solution would be, as Kevin suggests, to refresh the token with a cron job (this works well if the expiration is time-based with a fixed interval).

There are some details missing. Can the next token be obtained in advance, before the current one expires? Can you have two tokens (old one expiring soon and the fresh one) at the same time? If technically possible, are there any costs prohibiting the idea of getting tokens again and again in order to always have one that is valid?

Answer to the first question: yes, it can be obtained in advance but once the new one is acquired, it invalidates the previous one.

You could run a separate script to fetch the token then save it in sql using a cron job.

A cron job the is probably the best solution where periodically the cached token is refreshed before it can possibly expire guaranteeing whoever reads the token has a non-expired one. If that is not doable or convenient, then here is a way of implementing a quasi-lock in your MySQL database:
For the sake of generality, I will assume you have some table called credentials with a row with columns service_name (the name of a service for which a token is required) and token (the actual token required for the service), refresh_token (the refresh token required for getting a new token) and expiration (a timestamp of when the token expires or preferably a bit before). Then whenever the token is required, the SQL issued is:
SELECT token, refresh_token, expiration < now() as expired FROM credentials
WHERE service_name = 'some service name'
FOR UPDATE;

I have assumed that the connection being used is not in auto-commit mode (otherwise you will need an initial BEGIN TRANSACTION). This will force one-at-a-time access for every client trying to read or refresh the token and only the first client will get in and the remaining clients will be blocked.
After the row is read, you can check whether expired is 1 or 0. If it is 1 (which will be the case for the first client who is executing this SQL when the token is expired), you proceed to use the refresh token to get a new token and then update the token and expiration columns:
UPDATE credentials SET token = 'some new value', expiration = some_timestamp
WHERE service_name = 'some_service_name';
COMMIT;

If, however, expired is 0, then just execute:
ROLLBACK;

Addendum
Regardless of whether the the above SQL or a cron job that periodically refreshes the token or a token server that does all database access is used, there is a potential problem depending on whether refreshing a token invalidates a previously obtained valid token. Consider the following scenario where tokens are refreshed using a a cron job:

The cron job refreshes the token, which will expire in 30 days. The cron job runs every 29 days.
Client 1 obtains the current token right before the cron job is scheduled to run again.
The cron job then kicks off and obtains a new token.

Question: Is the token that Client 1 obtained, which would have otherwise remained valid for a full day, now invalid due to the cron job refreshing the token? Or is there a grace period where both tokens are usable?
Depending on the answer, the client may have to be prepared for authentication to fail due to an invalid token and to retry with an updated token.
If there is a grace period allowing both tokens to be valid, as long as a refresh is done a reasonable amount of time before the token would have otherwise expired, then having a single token refresher (either a cron job or token server) greatly simplifies client code. The client just has to fetch the token from the database (no locking required) or request it from a token server and it should be valid as long as it is used within the grace period.

Just to clarify, though, this external API takes 3 seconds on average to refresh (I know it's weird, but details do not matter). Suppose at some point the existing token expires, and 2k requests relying on this token run concurrently, will this be a problem for MySQL to lock?

I don’t think it’s a problem for MySQL as far as being able to lock out access while the token is being refreshed but these 2K users will be delayed for at least 3 seconds. But even if you go with a periodically run cron job, you still have the problem of locking out other users while the refresh is being done. This job would be run at a time where you would hopefully have low volume.

An alternate approach is to have a “token server” that users request the latest token from. It is only the server that is accessing the credentials and so no database locking is required.

The thing is the new token will instantly invalidate the existing one thus in current client code, I’ll have to manually check if the token obtained is valid and if not, I’ve provided a force refresh parameter to counteract the scenario you’ve described above.

I personally do not favor the idea of separating the token service into a stand-alone server since it downgrades the maintainability (correct me if I’m wrong)
